# Issue with adding event listener to anchors inside aura:unescapedHtml

Tags: lightning-aura-components

Facing a weird problem with `aura:unescapedHtml` tag.

Background: Working on adding custom onclick handler for formula fields in lightning component; navigation using `$A.get("e.force:navigateToURL")`.

If I do not use `aura:unescapedHtml` tag, with hardcoded HTML content; code works and add click listener. Apparently it does not work with that tag.

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome" extends="c:Base">

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onInit}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="value" type="Object" required="false" access="public" description="Value of formula"/>

    <div class="slds-card" aura:id="container" id="{!'container-' + globalId}">
        <aura:unescapedHtml value="{!v.value}"/>
    </div>

    <!-- With the following hardcoded content, listener is added -->
    <!--
        <div class="slds-card" aura:id="container">
            <a href="/0033D00000NbRmxQAF" target="_blank">Test contact 1</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            <a href="/0033D00000NbRmwQAF" target="_blank">Test contact 2</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            <a href="https://www.google.nl/" target="_blank">google.com</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
            <span>No link</span>
        </div>
    -->
</aura:component>
```

Controller.js

```
({
    onInit: function (component, event, helper) {

        var value = '<a href="/0033D00000NbRmxQAF" target="_blank">Test contact 1</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;' +
            '<a href="/0033D00000NbRmwQAF" target="_blank">Test contact 2</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;' +
            '<a href="https://www.google.nl/" target="_blank">google.com</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;' +
            '<span>No link</span>-test';
        component.set("v.value", value);

        setTimeout($A.getCallback(function() {

            // javascript version - doesn't work
            var container = document.getElementById('container-' + component.getGlobalId());
            var anchors = document.querySelectorAll("a");

            // lightning version - doesn't work as well
            /*
            var container = component.find("container").getElement();
            var anchors = container.childNodes;
            */

            for(var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
                var anchor = anchors[i];
                $A.util.addClass(anchor, "custom-anchors");
                anchor.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
                    var href = this.getAttribute("href");
                    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
                    urlEvent.setParams({
                        "url": href
                    });
                    urlEvent.fire();
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            }
        }), 1000);
    }
})
```

Stumble upon this one, please share if you have any insights. Thanks for your time!

---

Looks like the anchors aren't available with - `component.find("container").getElement().childNodes.length` and I get error due to locker service as:

> Exception: TypeError: Illegal invocation at HTMLCollection.remoteFunction

Comment: noticed a few thinkgs in your code, this resource might help you improve it--> [Lightning Components Developer Guide
 Anchor Tag: <a>](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_supported_html_tags_a.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your reply gminero,  This was just an example, in real life the value would be fetched from a formula field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of my colleague, got a ridiculously easy solution. We don't have to those DOM manipulation techniques.

Instead use `lightning:formattedRichText` which opens all the anchors/links in value [formula field in my case] in standard way.